# Angular - Declare nested Interface object Array

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

As I am new to Angular and wanted to use the right design principles, I wanted to make use of Interfaces for the data structure.

Here is the JSON response from the server:

```
{
  "appGroup": "Brokerage",
  "appName": "app-api",
  "appType": "Mulesoft",
  "config": "tmxpath,",
  "dashboard": "dashboard",
  "healthCheckURL": "api/ping",
  "hostList": [
    {
      "hostID": "host1",
      "port": 8080,
      "domain": "sampletmxdomain"
    },
    {
      "hostID": "host2",
      "port": 443,
      "domain": "tmxdomain2"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this, as you can see `hostList`  is an array of object. So I am not able to define and use the interface and object.

Here's what I have right now:

**The Interface**

```
export interface IAppOnboard {
  appName: string;
  appGroup: string;
  appType: string;
  config: string[];
  dashboard: string;
  healthCheckURL: string;
  hostList: Ihost[];
}
export interface Ihost{
  hostID: string;
  port: number;
  domain?: string;
}
```

**Interface Object**

```
  IHostsOb: Ihost[] = [{
    hostID: '',
    port: null,
    domain: ''
  }];
  IAppOnboardOb : IAppOnboard ={
    appName: '',
    appGroup: '',
    appType: '',
    config: [],
    dashboard: '',
    healthCheckURL: '',
    hostList: this.IHostsOb
  };
```

I ended up defining the interface object initialization in the above manner, but somehow it doesn't seems right and causing problems. Could I please get some help here?

Before giving any negative votes, please keep in mind that I have gone through some posts but couldn't find a solution that works for me.

**EDIT**

The doubt came into my mind because there was an error I was facing:

```
this.onboardingService.getOnboardingDashboardData(this.dlArray).subscribe((res: any) => {
    const selectedApp = res.applications.find(application => application.appName === app);
    if(selectedApp){
        let k;
        this.IHostsOb = selectedApp.hostList;
        this.IAppOnboardOb.config = selectedApp.hostList[0].config;
        for(k in selectedApp.hostList){
this.addHostPort(selectedApp.hostList[k].hostID,selectedApp.hostList[k].port,selectedApp.hostList[k].hostID.domain)  //This line  Works Fine
            this.IHostsOb[k].hostID = selectedApp.hostList[k].hostID;
            this.IHostsOb[k].port = selectedApp.hostList[k].port;
            this.IHostsOb[k].domain = selectedApp.hostList[k].domain;
            this.IAppOnboardOb.hostList.push(selectedApp.hostList[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above function assigns all the object elements in the array with same values.

Ex: the `IAppOnboardOb`'s `hostlist` becomes this:

```
"hostList": [
    {
      "hostID": "host1",
      "port": 8080,
      "domain": "sampletmxdomain"
    },
    {
      "hostID": "host1",
      "port": 8080,
      "domain": "sampletmxdomain"
    }]
```

**N.B.** `selectedApp` has the structure **similar** to that of the interface defined. not same.

Comment: _I ended up defining the interface object initialization in the above manner, but somehow it doesn't seems right and causing problems. Could I please get some help here?_ could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Your interfaces declaration is correct.

Have a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/csan7L81/

```
 const iHostsOb: Ihost[] = [{
    hostID: '',
    port: null,
    domain: ''
  }];
  const iAppOnboardOb: IAppOnboard = {
    appName: '',
    appGroup: '',
    appType: '',
    config: [],
    dashboard: '',
    healthCheckURL: '',
    hostList: iHostsOb
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface and the way you create the objects seems fine to me. If you specify the nature of your problem, would be great. Meanwhile, here are two things I noticed:

- it's good practice to call interfaces in CamelCase with an `I` in front. Might be a typo, but I'd call the interface `IHost` rather than `Ihost`;
- compared the JSON you showed in the question, the `env` property is missing in the `Ihost` interface you created;

(I wanted to reply to your question with a comment, but I don't have the necessary reputation)

Comment: yes, it was a typo. (`IHost`). Also, that `env` part doesn't matter(no use). I have removed it.